# how do I join two partitions with gparted?

Tags: partitioning

[image: partitions]

I'm in this bad situation: EFI/  unallocated/ext4 boot/swap/ubuntu/ntfs

how do I bring 'unallocated' before ntfs and merge it with ubuntu? Do I need ntfs? Is it a windows thing?

Thank you for your answers and no, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I looked pretty hard at this and even tho there are many similar answered questions, none of them apply to my case unfortunately

Comment: Dear Matigo, thank you again. Is there a way to do it with gparted? I would really like to avoid this much of extra work as I would have to rebuild my installer

Comment: ok ok, goddam. I solved it. Thank you both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gparted will allow you to move partitions - so really no problem. In this case, you would move the boot partition all the way to the left, then move the swap partition all the way to the left. That's as easy as double clicking on the partitions, and dragging the partition left or right in the dialog box.

Here's a partition with free space before it:
[image]

Now we have dragged it to the left and are ready to begin a move operation:
[image]

So, once you moved the first two partitions, you will have the ext4 partition and the unallocated area next to each other. Now you can grow the ext4 partition to the left (resize it), or you can move the ext4 partition all the way to the left, and then grow it to the right (resize it). The former seems safer to me - no additional files moved. Please note: all of this moving of partitions will be very slow and is dangerous so you must back everything up! Worst case scenario here is that you will not be able to start your operating system when you are done!

As a rule growing (resizing) partitions right is easy and quick, but moving or growing (resizing) to the left involves actually moving data and is slower and more dangerous.

Now, please note!!! Having said all this, a simpler solution would be to create a new ext4 partition in the unallocated part just where it is now (no need to move anything else). You can then mount this new partition in your linux system and use it as you will. For instance, it could be mounted as /data and used to store data - but you can call it anything you like it will just be more room for your files. This would be the safest option if you don't have a good backup strategy in place and aren't ready to handle repairing errors if anything goes wrong.

Note - this answer was originally posted Feb 7, 2022 and was revised May 8, 2022 to correct an error in how I was explaining gparted move operations.